# Clang_Complete only works for C standard headers but not C++ standard headers on MacOS

Tags: c++, vim, vim-plugin, clang-complete

So I have been using NeoVim for some time and installed the clang_complete plugin.
It works well with neovim when I am working in C files.
It even works for my c++ project files when I add the include directory to the .clang_compete file as

```sh
-Isrc/include
```

[image]

[image]

But it does not work for standard c++ header files.

I installed llvm in my macos with brew

```sh
brew install llvm
```

It is installed at /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.0_1/ and linked at /usr/local/opt/llvm/

[image]

[image]

My ~/.zshrc file:

```sh
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
ctags=/usr/local/bin/ctags
export CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
export CPATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"

alias gcc="clang"
alias g++="clang++"
```

My init.vim file:

```sh
let g:clang_library_path='/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib'
let g:clang_user_options='|| exit 0'
let g:clang_user_options = '-std=c++14 -Wall -DDEGUB -I/usr/local/llvm/include'
```

I also tried to change my .clang_complete to :

```sh
I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1/
-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/
```

But it does not work for C++ standard libraries.

Comment: If you use the paths returned by `clang++ -E -xc++ - -Wp,-v < /dev/null` does it work? (Or may are they the same paths?)

Comment: @LucHermitte it returns
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory 
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/opt/llvm/include
 /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.0_1/lib/clang/10.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include

Comment: @LucHermitte i included those paths in .clang_complete but still doesn't work :(

Comment: I got the vector completion working after adding both of these to .clang_complete
-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1
-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/clang/10.0.0/include

But the include still doesn't seem to work.